# Mongo DB Error "The server is in quiesce mode and will shut down"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently getting a Mongo error - "NotPrimaryError: The server is in quiesce mode and will shut down".

I have a CRON job that runs every day after midnight that just retrieves some stuff from the DB and then resubmits it, and this error comes up every 2-3 days at around the same time. After it, the DB restarts, and everything continues normally.
It doesn't seem that this is a RAM problem because there is a spike but there are more than 6 GB free.
I've tried to "paginate" the query set because I thought that it couldn't be loaded in memory but this still happens.
I've searched everywhere but I can't find a possible solution for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
The last time this happened was on the 21st at 01:09 AM and this happens before it:

```
{“t”:{"$date":“2022-01-21T01:08:32.753+00:00”},“s”:“I”, “c”:“COMMAND”, “id”:21581, “ctx”:“conn32”,“msg”:“Received replSetStepUp request”}
{“t”:{"$date":“2022-01-21T01:08:32.753+00:00”},“s”:“I”, “c”:“ELECTION”, “id”:4615661, “ctx”:“conn32”,“msg”:“Starting an election due to step up request”}
{“t”:{"$date":“2022-01-21T01:08:32.754+00:00”},“s”:“I”, “c”:“ELECTION”, “id”:21437, “ctx”:“conn32”,“msg”:“Skipping dry run and running for election”,“attr”:{“newTerm”:80}}
{“t”:{"$date":“2022-01-21T01:08:32.754+00:00”},“s”:“I”, “c”:“REPL”, “id”:6015303, “ctx”:“conn32”,“msg”:“Waiting for in-progress election to complete before finishing stepup”}
```

The number of connections at that time was 131 which shouldn't be a problem. There is a spike in CPU and memory usage but there's plenty left. There's also no significant message that happens before this that I could find. There are some `Slow query` warnings but they show up at different intervals and it doesn't seem to be connected with this issue.

Comment: The node enters quiesce mode while it is shutting down.  Check the mongod log to see why it shutdown.

Comment: @Joe I've added the information in the post. Not sure if that's all that's needed.

Comment: Those log messages show the node becoming primary, is there any indication of why it shut down?

Comment: If it's not a problem, could I send you a private chat? The logs are huge and I'm not sure that I can extract the information that's needed.

Comment: Did it get solved?? I am also facing similar issue!